# Como pasar un dato de mi BD a todas las vistas en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

En mi base de datos tengo una tabla con informacion de mi pagina como logos, descripión etc. Y necesito utilizar en este caso un logo que tengo almacenado en bd en todas las vistas. Como puedo hacer eso? no tengo idea en dónde agregar el codigo y estoy buscando información pero no me ha funcionado...

Solo en una vista he logrado hacerlo pero es por el controlador que retorna la vista y alli envio la variable a usar con el contenido:

```
public function index()
{
    $configs = ConfigPage::all();
    return view('admin.configPage.index', compact('configs'));
}
```

Mas que todo necesito que esa variable **$configs** sea global.

Answer (score 2):

> Una aproximación sería crear a nivel de la clase un método constructor que reciba a la propiedad y por dentro la iguale a la consulta que pretendes hacer al modelo en cuestión, esto generará que dicha consulta se pueda reutilizar solo retornando la propiedad en cada método del controlador que la contiene.

Aquí declaramos una propiedad que le indicamos sea de tipo `protected`

```
class DemoController extends Controller
{
    protected $data;
}
```

De manera continua creas la estructura de un método mágico `__construct()` al que le pasaremos como argumento la propiedad antes declarada para que se inicialice al momento de crearse la clase así:

```
class DemoController extends Controller
{
    protected $data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data = Modelo::all();
    }
}
```

Una vez hecho lo anterior esta propiedad `$data` contiene el resultado de la consulta a tu Modelo, pudiendola usar en cualquier otro método que quieras retorne datos a tus vistas, así por ejemplo:

Por ejemplo en el método index así retornarías los datos de tu consulta:

```
public function index()
{

    return $this->data;
}
```

Como puedes observar ya solo retornamos a la propiedad de la clase y no le asignamos como valor consulta alguna.

Lo mismo puedes hacer en cualquier otro método, por ejemplo uno que se llame `index2`

```
public function index2()
{

    return $this->data;
}
```

Y ya en tu vista pudieras ver el resultado de la query de este modo o en un HTML como tu lo desees

```
[{"id":1,"name":"el-user","email":"mail2@mail.com","email_verified_at":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]
```

Para poder iterar los datos en la vista, los mandas con el método `compact()` de este modo:

```
public function index2()
{

    return view('tuvista')->with(['data' => $this->data]);
}
```

Posterior en tu vista usarás el bucle `foreach` para iterar la colección devuelta así

```
@foreach($this->data as $dato)
    {{ $dato->columnaNombre1 }}
    {{ $dato->columnaNombre2 }}
    {{ $dato->columnaNombreN }}
@endforeach
```

Donde `columnaNombre` son los nombres de las columnas de tu tabla

**REFERENCIAS**

- [loops in views Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#loops)

Comment: Me parece bien... pero lo que no se es dónde agregar el código del metodo magico **_contruct**, en mi controlador que ya tengo o creo un archivo nuevo? Apenas estoy iniciando aprender laravel... perdón:(

Comment: y ahora como muestro por ejemplo  solo "email" en mi vista? decías que usando return $this->data devuelve todos los datos pero ahora como lo envio como si fuera utilizar compact?

Comment: mmm en realidad no, osea está bien que devuelva todos los datos así como lo mostrabas en la ultima parte de tu respuesta (devuelve todos los datos "id", "name"...etc). pero lo que no sé es como  mandar a llamar un dato de esos ya en mi vista

Comment: pero en el foreach debe ir ($this->data as $data) ?

Comment: revisa la actualización que haré @JoseFranc

Comment: solo una ultima....el metodo _costruct lo debo agregar en todos mis controladores?

Comment: @JoseFranc Esto que coloqué como respuesta hace global a la propiedad `$data` dentro del alcance del controlador donde esta declarada, sin embargo si ocupas esto en todos tus controladores, si deberás repetir el proceso **al menos desde la lógica de mi respuesta**, puedes probar con mi solución o esperar a que otros usuarios aporten

Comment: Claro! Muchas Gracias... BENDICIONES

Answer (score 1):

**Si entiendo lo que quieres hacer**, esa tabla lo que tiene es informacion para el diseño de las vistas y lo que quieres es leer el contenido en cada una de las vistas,

Lo que tienes que hacer es lo siguiente;

1) En cada controlador que llame a una vista que desea usar los datos de la tabla debes colocar la carga del modelo de esta para volver hacer la consulta:

ejemplo:

al principio de cada controlador debe tener el llamado del modelo Configpage

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Configpage;
```

2) Debes hacer el llamado de la consulta en cada metodo de los controladores que vas a  tomar los datos.

Ejemplo:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $configs = ConfigPage::all();

    $alumno = User::find($id); // la var $id corresponde al id usuario
    return view('admin.show')->with(compact('alumno','configs'));  

}
```

fijate que estoy pasando tanto los datos para la configuracion del config como la consulta de alumno. (esto es lo que tiene que hacer del lado del controlador), en el area de la vista para tomar los datos lo llamas por el nombre que le colocaste ej:  $config->logo  , $config->descripcion.

OTRA IDEA SERIA hacer un metodo __construct() hacer la consulta y pasar los datos en variable globales, seria cuestion de probarlo y esto funcionaria solo dentro de un controlador, para otro controlador deberas repetir el codigo.